# Получение почты с gmail

Tags: android, gmail

Подскажите имеется ли сейчас возможность получения писем с gmail без использования рекомендованного google метода
[developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android)

пробовал код на подобие вот этого

```
MailSSLSocketFactory sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
sf.setTrustAllHosts(true);

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imap.ssl.socketFactory", sf);

// Get session
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
//session.setDebug(true);

// Get the store
Store store = session.getStore("imap");
System.out.println("Establishing connection with IMAP server.");

store.connect("host", 993, "username", "password");

// List all folders (including subfolders)
Folder[] allFolders = store.getDefaultFolder().list("*");

store.close();
```

на этапе соединения получаю ошибку 
(небезопасные приложения в настройках аккаунта разрешены)